# Can we display geographical border in Google Map V3 as we do in Google Earth, in satellite view?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-earth, satellite

Can we display geographical borders of country in satellite view of Google Maps V3, similarly the way border is displayed in Google Earth in satellite view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe something like this should give you borders in satellite view.

```
var custom-Style = [
                    { featureType: "administrative.country", elementType: "all", stylers: [{ visibility: "on"}] },
                    { featureType: "administrative.land_parcel", elementType: "all", stylers: [{ visibility: "on"}] }
                   ];

var myOptions = {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), myOptions);

var styledMapOptions = {
    name: "custom-Style"
}

var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(custom-Style, styledMapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('custom-Style', customMapType);
map.setMapTypeId('custom-Style');
```