# Highlight Land-Sea Borders in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to highlight the land-sea borders in Google Maps via a styled map?

I know that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502807/can-we-display-geographical-border-in-google-map-v3-as-we-do-in-google-earth-in) recommends activating `administrative.land_parcel`. However, when I activate the strokes in the [Google Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) for *Land parcel*, nothing shows up.

The best I can do is highlight the strokes for Country and Province, which only activates within-land borders.

Answer (score 0):

The water feature on the Google Maps Wizard that you linked to will highlight all water. There is a Weight option that appears to affect the border stroke width, but I don't see a way to get a transparent fill with a solid color in the Wizard.

From the [styling documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), it appears you should be able to use
    water.geometry.stroke
and
    water.geometry.fill
to select the water and its border separately, then style them to get whatever edge effect you're looking for. You may just need to adjust the Weight and Color properties of the stroke and leave the fill alone.

One caveat is that using the built-in water feature will select lakes as well as seas/oceans. This may or may not be your desired behavior.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that but it has the same result as setting the strokes for *Water* on the Wizard. A fill can be set (just like the Wizard) but strokes without fill does nothing (just like the Wizard).

Comment: I had assumed that was just a limitation of the wizard. I guess not. That's unfortunate.

Comment: water geometry.stroke color seems not to work, no solutions? `featureType:"water",elementType:"geometry.stroke",stylers:[{color:"#000000"}]` https://jsfiddle.net/4csvjgfq/2/